# How to get Current User credentials in windows 7 with a Windows Service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, active-directory

I'm trying to get currently user credentials with a windows service in Windows 7.

When I run the code below on DEBUG mode *(notice that, when I run this on DEBUG mode, the winservice runs on my User instead of LocalSystem)*, there is no problem. However, when the WinService runs on LocalSystem account on the machine I cannot get current user from active directory when I run the codes as "Released" (not debug) and as Windows Service?

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DomainName))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
    {
        adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + Environment.UserName + ")";
        SearchResult adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();

        UserInternalEmail = GetProperty(adSearchResult, "mail");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalSystem has no rights outside the local system, so it is pretty clear the AD/LDAP is going to reject it's query. Just run the service under a AD/LDAP/domain account.

Comment: Could you elaborate AD/LDAP/domain a little further? And I also run a desktop application with the same winservice when the win service running on LocalSystem. So, shouldnt I be able to check the active directory from localsystem?

Comment: LDAP has no idea who LocalSystem is, it is unique to every Windows box.

Comment: OK. So how can I run a Windows Service under AD/LDAP/domain account,
I run as this.ProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

Comment: You just provide the user details and password. You can simply do this via the Services Control Panel to test.

Comment: This Windows Service will be a mass installation on over 70 computers, therefore it seems LocalSystem could be the only account that the service can run on to. Besides, no user who are logged into will not have administrator privilages

Comment: The user does not have to be logged it to run a service. (IIRC, it needs a 'Run as Service' permission). I dont think you will need admin privileges.

Comment: I'm truly grateful for your help. 

But I believe I did not understand your way of solution quite. You might think I'm stupid or something :) ...

Are you talking about this code in ServiceInstaller.Designer.cs?
this.ProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.<which user>;
this.ProcessInstaller.Password = null;
this.ProcessInstaller.Username = null;

Is there any piece of code you can provide?

Thank you very much again.

Comment: You don't have any example codes to provide? I really need to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can just fill the username and password fields with the required text (strings).

Comment: The only user I have is my own and unfortunately has no admin rights.
I tried with System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User (and my password) - didn't work 
I tried with System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService(and my password) - didn't work 


is there a way around while running the service under LocalSystem?